# How to make Camera rotating around a point?

Tags: webgl, three.js

How to make Camera rotating around a point? I start to do this, but i have some problems when phi = 90 and -90, and with that in such way of rotating i don't roll camera

```
    theta = - ( ( event.clientX - lastLeft ) * 360 /window.innerWidth ) + onMouseDownTheta;
    phi = ( ( event.clientY - lastTop ) * 360 /window.innerHeight ) + onMouseDownPhi;
    var cosPhi = Math.cos( phi * Math.PI / 180 );
    var sinPhi = Math.sin( phi * Math.PI / 180 );
    var sinTheta = Math.sin( theta * Math.PI / 180 );
    var cosTheta = Math.cos( theta * Math.PI / 180 );

   camera.position.x = - radious * sinTheta * cosPhi;
   camera.position.y = radious * sinPhi;
   camera.position.z = radious * cosTheta * cosPhi;

   camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))


  if(phi > 90){
     u = u*(-1);                
     camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, u, 0);
  }
  camera.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: You mean that at some points the camera flips around but you want your rotation more like this: http://braingl.de ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common types of camera controls have been built right into three.js and can be implemented easily.

Many of the examples already use these control interfaces, and you can take advantage of them yourself as simply as:

```js
var scene, renderer, camera, controls, clock;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAR, FAR);
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

    clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // ... (Scene setup)

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);

    // Fetch the delta from THREE.js' clock.
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    // Pass it to the camera controller.
    controls.update(delta);

    renderer.render();
}

// Load up the scene when the page finishes loading.
// This can be done a few different ways, this one is
// useful for script tags embedded in the <head> of the page.
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

Alternatively you could take a look at the source code for the controls if you want to write your own, to see how the built-in controllers manipulate the camera:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js